# Flutter Flatbutton onpressed not working while trying to open phone dialer

Tags: android, flutter

Hello new to flutter here. I am trying to open phone dialer with a predefined phone number after pressing Call button that is Flatbutton inside Positioned, but it is not working and does not show any error either. I tried printing some values on onpressed as well but it did not print any. I have called this widget in another dart file.

Here i am using url_launcher package to launch the phone dialog.
If any other alternative way please help.

(Removed some unimportant design codes below)

```
class CallCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CallCardState createState() => _CallCardState();
}

class _CallCardState extends State<CallCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Positioned(
        bottom: -170,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Text(
                'Are you feeling well today?',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
              ),

              Text(
                'Give us a call or visit our website.',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 23.0,
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                    color: Color(0xff9ce47c),
                    onPressed: () {
                      final String phone = "01-4441577";
                      launch(phone);
                      print('here');
                    },
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          LineAwesomeIcons.phone,
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Call Now',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                  
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          
        ));
  }
}
```

This is the code where I have called this widget (inside Stack)

```
child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                _backgroundCover(),
                //content inside header
                Positioned(
                  top: 80,
                  left: 30,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Hello User',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 36,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                      // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 200.0)),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            LineAwesomeIcons.power_off,
                            size: 40.0,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            DialogHelper.exit(context);
                            // await _auth.signOut();
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                CallCard(),
                
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you add a code of the `Stack` widget ? @Mr Bond.

Comment: i added it, (CallCard())

Comment: Kindly add the code  snippet of the Stack to your question so I can help. @Mr Bond

Comment: Hey @TimilehinJegede thanks for your comment, I solved it by simply removing it from the Stack widget. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ok with this code.

```
launch('tel:$yourPhoneNo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting the print before launch? It could be that launch is getting stuck and then the print never gets reached (this has happened to me with certain packages).

I am not sure how launch works with phone numbers but you may want to look into if youre using it properly.

Comment: also one more thing, what are your intentions with positioned? is Stack an ancestor?

Comment: yes Stack is an parent, i dont know someone told me to use Positioned so i did